# Huge constructor for messages/names definition

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, variadic-functions, builder

I want to allow name and message customisation in both my lexer and parsers. The parser/lexer must be able to select a specific message or name, e.g.:

> messageManager.tokenName.eofToken

Here, `eofToken` would be a `String`. `tokenName` would be a set of names for lexer tokens and `messageManager` would be a structure like `{ parserMessage, lexerMessage, contextName, tokenName }`

However, I want the message customisation very directly constructed. I don't want something like:

```
TokenName tokenName = new TokenName();
tokenName.eofToken = "end of file";
tokenName.identifier = "identifier";
tokenName.keyword = "keyword";
tokenName.regExpLiteral = "regexp' literal";
// much more...
```

I want something like:

```
new TokenName(
    "end of file",
    "identifier",
    "keyword",
    ...
)
```

I know we just need to define parameters and assign them to the corresponding variables, but I don't want a huge constructor like the one I had in my previous parser:

```
public TokenNames(
    String booleanLiteral,
    String eofToken,
    String identifier,
    String punctuator,
    String keyword,
    String numericLiteral,
    String nullLiteral,
    String regExpLiteral,
    String stringLiteral,
    String xmlName,
    String xmlMarkup,
    String xmlPunctuator,
    String xmlTagCharacters,
    String xmlText
)
{
    this.booleanLiteral = booleanLiteral;
    this.eofToken = eofToken;
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.punctuator = punctuator;
    this.keyword = keyword;
    this.numericLiteral = numericLiteral;
    this.nullLiteral = nullLiteral;
    this.regExpLiteral = regExpLiteral;
    this.stringLiteral = stringLiteral;
    this.xmlName = xmlName;
    this.xmlMarkup = xmlMarkup;
    this.xmlPunctuator = xmlPunctuator;
    this.xmlTagCharacters = xmlTagCharacters;
    this.xmlText = xmlText;
}
```

I believe it's possible with arrays or varargs (more readable). How to?

Comment: Consider using a builder.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch A name cannot relate to other, neither messages, so a builder won't be sufficient at all.

Comment: [What](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But in my case I only wanted a fixed length of parameters, so I wanted to construct directly. HOWEVER, I've now found it really better to use a builder, because it'll make the code more maintanaible, so I'll try this one. Will be more verbose, but looks good

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Seriously, it'll still be large. I still want it all fixed, so the unique solution is to use arrays. :/

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the builder pattern is the most obvious solution in here (and the correct one).

But I would like to draw your attention to the fact there is a lot of fields that can be encapsulated by their own classes.

The following fields can be collected into an `XMLDescription` class:

```
String xmlName;
String xmlMarkup;
String xmlPunctuator;
String xmlTagCharacters;
String xmlText;
```

The next ones can be grouped by a `LiteralDescription` class:

```
String numericLiteral;
String nullLiteral;
String regExpLiteral;
String stringLiteral;
```

Think the problem over once more: if there is a chance to shorten a number of the fields to 3 (an extreme bound according to good practices), the constructor can be used instead of the builder.

> I believe it's possible with arrays or varargs (more readable).

Please, don't do that - it's an error-prone approach. You are coupling an index of the array with a corresponding field. Such code, hard to maintain and document, causes an API user

- to read a documentation if any provided,
- to poke around in the sources if no provided,
- to follow to any API change believing that nothing is changed.

Answer (score 2):

Define class like this:

```
public class Token {

    private String booleanLiteral;
    private String eofToken;

    ...

    public Token withBooleanLiteral(String booleanLiteral) {
      this.booleanLiteral = booleanLiteral;
      return this;
    }

    public Token withEofToken(String eofToken) {
      this.eofToken = eofToken;
      return this;
    }

    ...

  }
```

You'll get

```
Token token = new Token()
    .withBooleanLiteral("something");
```

Check out [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Wither) library and `@Wither` annotation. It does everything for you.